# Neo4J 3.4 how does `date` function work?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I upgraded a Neo4J v3.3 to v3.4 to try out the new spatial and temporal functions.

I'm trying very simple queries. Once with the date function and one without. The results are different.

`match (r:Model) where r.open_date>"2018-04-26" return count(r);`

Result is 19283.

`match (r:Model) where r.open_date>date("2018-04-26") return count(r);`

Result is 0.

What is the way to use the new functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]

The new [temporal types](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/values/#property-types), like `Date` and `Duration`, are really special types, and it does not make sense to compare them directly to strings or numbers.

Assuming `r.open_date` has the [right format](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-specify-date), this should work:

```
MATCH (r:Model)
WHERE DATE(r.open_date) > DATE("2018-04-26")
RETURN
```

Also, the the following query may be more performant (since a second DATE object does not need to be constructed):

```
MATCH (r:Model)
WHERE TOSTRING(DATE(r.open_date)) > "2018-04-26"
RETURN
```

Comment: I'm getting an error your way: `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Text cannot be parsed to a Date
"2017-11-06 00:00:00"`

Comment: I think the correct format is `2015-07-21T21:40:32.142+0100`

Comment: If the time portion will always be midnight, you can just use the first 10 characters of your string: `date(LEFT(r.open_date, 10))`.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do something similar to that. Reformatting all dates. Just as trial, then if all goes well I'll move to production. Thanks